# How to hover to display a div without expanding the size of the container (li)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an UL. Each LI element contains an image and a div element. The div element is supposed to be hidden and shows up when the user hovers over the image to display more information about the image. And I just want the div element to just overlay on top of the other li elements.

The problem is when the div element is shown, it expands the size of the li element and pushes other li elements out of place. I figured out a solution to this by specifying the size of the li element to a specific size with px. However, I don't really want to do that because it's not good responsive design. When I use percentages, it does not work because the size of the UL element increases when the div element is shown, therefore, the size of li also increases automatically.

```css
#list {
 list-style:none;
 overflow:initial;
 width:20%;
}
#list li {
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 overflow:visible;
}
.additionalInfo {
 position:relative;
 background-color:white;
 top:20px;
 left:40px;
 display:none;
 }
.clearer{
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
<li class="listItem">
 <p>image here.....................</p>
 <div class="additionalInfo">
  <p>additional info</p>
  <p>additonal info</p>
 </div>
</li>
<li class="listItem">
 <p>image here.....................</p>
 <div class="additionalInfo">
  <p>additional info</p>
  <p>additonal info</p>
 </div>
</li>
<li class = ".clearer"></li>
```

[Demo with image substituted with just plain text for simplicity](https://jsfiddle.net/hduof4uk/).

Answer (score 1):

You have the positioning wrong. First, your `additionalInfo` divs should have

```
position: absolute;
```

and the containing `li` elements should have:

```
position: relative;
```

That way it works. Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/93pe7hdq/